# Error generating initial migration: The type or namespace name "Migrations" does not exist

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

I have 2 Visual Studio projects; a .net core web API 3.1 project used as startup for ef migrations and a class library containing the dbcontext. When I open a powershell window, navigate to the folder for my class library and execute `dotnet ef migrations add Initial --startup-project [path to csproj-file for the web API project]` the migrations folder with a snapshot file and the initial migration file is created.

But when I open the migration file in Visual Studio I get several compile errors, one of them complaining that `The type or namespace 'Migrations' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore'...` I can also see the auto generated migration file contains a using statement pointing to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations` which is marked as unnecessary and the documentation at [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations?view=efcore-3.1) clearly contains both the base `Migration` class and `MigrationBuilder` class referenced by the compiler.

I tried looking for both `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.All` on Nuget.org but none of them exist. Am I missing something obvious here? Why do the autogenerated migration files fail to compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I didn't look carefully enough at the msdn documentation for the Migration class. It is located in the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` assembly and after installing that Nuget package the project now compiles without errors.

Comment: same for me thanks , 2021 .net 5 u think they would have fixed this